# Python alternative to csvfix

Tags: python, text, csv, text-processing

sorry for bad English. I am working in sales and processing many prices. Most of the problems i have been solved (scheduling, processing queue, storing, converting from Excel 2003/2007 or Access, encoding etc...). One of the unresolved problem is processing csv files. I need tool with many configuration options. Most of needed is filter/search by manufacturer or skip rows which not follows some conditions - may be amount of product or it's price and may be other. I found tool that solve this task - [csvfix](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/) But there is disadvantages in it cause it can't work with non Latin alpabet. I searching alternative, may be you know? Best of all if it will be written on Python/Ruby. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a programmable tool or a finished application?  If the latter, take a look at [csved](http://csved.sjfrancke.nl/index.html). It offers lots of configuration and filtering options and handles non-ASCII data well (there also is a Unicode variant available. And it's cardware (free, but the author asks for a postcard).

Comment: Yes, it must be console tool, or whatever that can process without human intention, based on configuration